# USB C network connection between Macbook and PC Laptop?

Tags: networking, macos, usb, ethernet

I'd like to connect a Macbook Pro to a Dell XPS laptop so that I can have a direct Ethernet-type connection between the two laptops. This is so that I can remote desktop into the XPS laptop with minimal latency. Over Wifi there is noticeable lag.

I imagine I could make use of two USB C to Ethernet adapters with an Ethernet cable in between, but would it be possible to do the same with a simple USB C to USB C cable? Is it possible to share / bridge their networks in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, but only via Thunderbolt, not plain USB. Most systems (macOS, Linux, Windows 11<sup>1</sup>) can support IP-over-Thunderbolt (well, Ethernet-over-Thunderbolt) providing something equivalent to a 10 Gbps Ethernet connection.

As far as I know, the regular USB protocol doesn't really have an equivalent, even if the physical connectors allow you to plug the cable in. If one machine runs Linux, it *might* be possible to configure it as a USB "device" rather than a "host" (using the Linux "USB gadget" drivers), making it show up on the other device like a USB-Ethernet adapter, though this seems rather clunky.

<sup>1</sup> For macOS and Linux this is built in; I am not 100% sure whether this is built-in for Windows or whether it requires additional drivers.

> Over Wifi there is noticeable lag.

Try to connect *just one* of them to your LAN via regular Ethernet. It might be that the latency is not due to Wi-Fi in general, but specifically due to both devices being connected wirelessly to the same AP on the same channel (so the packets need twice the airtime as they're sent to the AP and *then* from the AP to the other device, in half-duplex).

Latency might also be caused by the Wi-Fi adapter's "Power saving" mode on the receiving machine. Power-saving wakes up the NIC only for a short time to receive replies after something was sent; it works well for a client but massively increases latency for a server.